# HTML video element in Microsoft Edge - Green frame issue

Tags: html, css, html5-video, microsoft-edge, webm

I am working on a scroll-based video system that works great in other browsers, but in edge, there are weird green frames in between the normal frames. I do not think this is to do with the scroll-based system, but more to do with the video file format - webm.

What could be causing this?

I have included a video to show the issue.

[click here](https://videobin.org/+15gc/1bfk.html)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check your video in MS Edge and Chrome browser. I found that with both browsers I can see those green frames.

You said that you think it is video file format **Webm** issue but when I check the video I noticed that it is .**OGG** file.

You can check this example with **Webm** file, it is working fine with Edge browser..

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" width="512" height="288" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```